# how to get mean of every element of a matrix .

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

I know how to get mean of a matrix . 
it is like this . sum of all values /n elements.

But I wonder that how to get mean of every element of a matrix in c++.

kindly help me in this regards . 
thanks

Comment: What does mean of every element of a matrix mean?

Comment: I want to get changes in every element of a matrix . so want to get mean and standard deviation of every element.

Comment: Mean would be equal to the element value and standard deviation would be zero.

Comment: I guess you are working with image matrix in C++. I don't know if there is any already existing function in C++, you can simply do a raster scan (row-column traversal) through the image and find pixels mean values.

Comment: yes , I am doing with image matrix. but I wonder how can I get mean of every element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems you have a matrix `M` that is varying with time ( or iterations of some kind). The mean that you want is actually a matrix of same size as `M`. Will the following steps should do the job?

1. Initialize mean matrix `m` of the size of `M` to zeros
2. Add the current value of `M` to `m`. So `m += M`
3. Increment counter `N` for number of iterations of `M`
4. Divide each element of `m` by `N`. So `m = m / N`.

Comment: I made a small example. how can I share it?

Comment: i did something like this on excel https://postimg.org/image/4ho8rc3niz/

Comment: Please correct me if i  did wrong in that small 3x3 example. thanks

Comment: i found here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30295799/1215702 , this seems like mean and standard deviation of each element of column.

Answer (score -1):

If the matrix is representing a image, take a gray(no color) image for example, it'a easy to understand. 
The element of value 0 is indicate this pixel is black, and element of value 127 tell you this position is white. 0 is darkest while 127 is brightest. The larger value, the more bright. Each pixel(matrix element) have a value indicate it's brightness. All the pixel composite a whole pic. The mean of all the element is wanting to know the average brightness of the image.

Comment: I am talking about mean of every element. not all elements or average brightness of image.